# Powershell - Create Large Number of Shares and Permissions

Tags: powershell, ntfs

I tried about a dozen PowerShell scripts that I found and not one even created a single share.

We are migrating from Win 2008 and SQL Server 2008 R2 to Windows 2012 and SQL Server 2014.

I have to create a ton of shares and assign a lot of varying permissions.

I'm looking for (ideally) a Powershell script (but can live with VB or anything else) that can go through a list of shares and permissions and create/assign them.

For example

```
E:\Folder1\A      Share1      Domain\Tom      Read
E:\Folder1\A      Share1      Domain\Dick     Full
E:\Folder1\A      Share1      Domain\Harry    Change
```

So it would go through every line, see if the share exists, if not create it, then assign the permissions.

Comment: This is literally a gimme the codez question.

Comment: Please show the code that you are working with, and let us know where it's failing you. From a quick `get-command '*share*'` on my Win8.1 box I see `New-NfsShare` and `Grant-NfsSharePermission` that look like they do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

On Server 2012R2 you can use the New-SmbShare cmdlet : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj635722(v=wps.630).aspx

On older versions you have to fall back to WMI to do it :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389393(v=vs.85).aspx (the article even has a PS example).

With Set-Acl you can set the ACLs for the shares.
As you can see all the tools to acomplish this are available in a default installation of Windows Server.